# Copy information from iCal to Google calendar

Tags: linux, macos, calendar, calendar.app

I am using OSX Leopard and would like to sync iCal with some other system so at home, on a Linux box, I can see the calendars. I thought about Google calendar, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Google Calendar help site](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/?hl=en), it is possible to [sync iCal with Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99355).

Answer (score 3):

To simply copy the information there, you can export your iCal calendars as .ics files, and then import them to Google Calendar with the web interface.

CalDAV syncing *is* possible without additional software, but can end up looking quite ugly if you have multiple calendars (Each calendar will display under a different account header or subfolder).

If you want Google-based calendars to appear in a normal list (just like MobileMe calendars would look) you do need additional software. I personally use [BusyMac software's](http://www.busymac.com/) product [BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/index.html)... it's a preference pane that allows you to sync iCal's backend with Google, completely seamlessly. [Spanning Sync 3](http://spanningsync.com/) is another option.